# Uniqueness of an absolute continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

Let $b_i$, $i=1,\ldots,K$, be Lipschitz-continuous vector fields from $D^n$ to $E^n$ where $D,E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are compact.

Let $S_i\subseteq E^n$, for $i=1,\ldots,K$, be non-empty and disjoint.

Let $x(t):\mathbb{R}_+\to E^n$ be absolutely continuous and such that $x(0)=x_0$ and $\dot{x}(t)=\sum_{i=1}^K \mathbf{1}\{x(t)\in S_i\} \, b_i(x(t))$ whenever $x(t)$ is differentiable, that is whenever $x(t)$ is in the interior of $S_i$, for some $i$. Assume also that such $x(t)$ exists.

**Question**: prove or disprove that such $x(t)$ is unique.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example, where uniqueness fails. Set $K=1$ and
$$ b: [1,e] \to [1,e]\,,\quad b(x) = x\,,$$
$S = (1,e)$ and $x_0 = 1$. Then both
$$ x(t) = 1\,,$$
and
$$ x(t) = \min(e^t, e) $$
are absolutely continuous functions satisfying
$$ \dot x(t) = \mathbf 1_{(1,e)}(x(t)) \cdot x(t)\,,$$
for all $t \in [0,\infty)$.

Comment: $x(t)$ must take values in $E$ (in this case, [0,1]), so $\min(e^t,t)$ would not satisfy the given hypotheses.

Comment: You are right, there was a mistake in my answer. The right choice is $D=E=[1,e]$.